# How can I whitelist a file or directory that is in my .gitignore?

Tags: projectile

In my Clojure projects, I like to keep my REPL namespace separate from my other source files, so I always have something like this in my `project.clj`:

```
:profiles {:dev {:source-paths ["dev"]
                 :repl-options {:init-ns user}}}
```

Since I only use that file (and its parent directory) for temporary definitions and experimentation and such, I don't want it in version control, so I put the whole directory in my `.gitignore`:

```
/dev/
```

So my project structure looks something like this:

```
myproject
├── dev
│   └── user.clj
├── .gitignore
├── project.clj
└── ...
```

Now, for the most part, Projectile works great for navigating around projects; I can use `C-c p f` to quickly switch to my source files, tests, documentation, `project.clj`, `.gitignore`, etc.

But I can't switch to my REPL namespace file! I tried adding a `.projectile` file to my project and playing around with that, but as far as I can tell, if a file is in `.gitignore`, there is *no way* to tell Projectile *not* to ignore it.

So my question is, is it possible to ignore a file or directory in Git but not in Projectile?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Since 2016-04-05](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile/commit/bd68bf45bad027d2f1c32ca88da9e7a01b67664a), you can use a bang prefix to override ignored profiles, as explained in [the docs](http://projectile.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/#ignoring-files). For instance, to override the `.gitignore` in the question for the files in the `/dev` folder, you could use a `.projectile` file that looks like this:

```
!/dev/
```

Comment: In 2019 this is not working. See here: https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile/issues/1322

Comment: It's now 

    +/dev/